# unable to find 'app:closeIconVisible' of material chips

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-chips

I am trying to use material components via support library. I get the following error when I use chip attributes that begins with "app:....". I haven't preferred to migrate to androidx since it is not stable yet. Should I download android studio 3.2 and migrate to androidx ? Could you give me some advice, please?
Thanks for your help in advance.

**error: attribute 'com.tarifis.tarifis:closeIconVisible' not found.**

```
 <android.support.design.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text"
        app:closeIconVisible="visible"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        />
```

Here is gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tarifis.tarifis"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, the source is open. Below is the snippet from the source that shows which attributes are available with the version of library that I am using. Since the library version that you are using is different from mine, I would suggest to find out for yourself in studio itself.

In order to find out, just Ctrl click on the *com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup* in the xml and follow through to the *com.google.material.android.chip.ChipDrawable* class' **loadFromAttributes()** method.

Here is a snippet for your quick reference:

```
private void loadFromAttributes(AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr, @StyleRes int defStyleRes) {
    TypedArray a = ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(this.context, attrs, styleable.ChipDrawable, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.setChipBackgroundColor(MaterialResources.getColorStateList(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_chipBackgroundColor));
    this.setChipMinHeight(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_chipMinHeight, 0.0F));
    this.setChipCornerRadius(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_chipCornerRadius, 0.0F));
    this.setChipStrokeColor(MaterialResources.getColorStateList(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_chipStrokeColor));
    this.setChipStrokeWidth(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_chipStrokeWidth, 0.0F));
    this.setRippleColor(MaterialResources.getColorStateList(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_rippleColor));
    this.setChipText(a.getText(styleable.ChipDrawable_chipText));
    this.setTextAppearance(MaterialResources.getTextAppearance(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_android_textAppearance));
    this.setChipIconEnabled(a.getBoolean(styleable.ChipDrawable_chipIconEnabled, false));
    this.setChipIcon(MaterialResources.getDrawable(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_chipIcon));
    this.setChipIconSize(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_chipIconSize, 0.0F));
    this.setCloseIconEnabled(a.getBoolean(styleable.**ChipDrawable_closeIconEnabled**, false));
    this.setCloseIcon(MaterialResources.getDrawable(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_closeIcon));
    this.setCloseIconTint(MaterialResources.getColorStateList(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_closeIconTint));
    this.setCloseIconSize(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_closeIconSize, 0.0F));
    this.setCheckable(a.getBoolean(styleable.ChipDrawable_android_checkable, false));
    this.setCheckedIconEnabled(a.getBoolean(styleable.ChipDrawable_checkedIconEnabled, false));
    this.setCheckedIcon(MaterialResources.getDrawable(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_checkedIcon));
    this.setShowMotionSpec(MotionSpec.createFromAttribute(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_showMotionSpec));
    this.setHideMotionSpec(MotionSpec.createFromAttribute(this.context, a, styleable.ChipDrawable_hideMotionSpec));
    this.setChipStartPadding(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_chipStartPadding, 0.0F));
    this.setIconStartPadding(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_iconStartPadding, 0.0F));
    this.setIconEndPadding(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_iconEndPadding, 0.0F));
    this.setTextStartPadding(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_textStartPadding, 0.0F));
    this.setTextEndPadding(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_textEndPadding, 0.0F));
    this.setCloseIconStartPadding(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_closeIconStartPadding, 0.0F));
    this.setCloseIconEndPadding(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_closeIconEndPadding, 0.0F));
    this.setChipEndPadding(a.getDimension(styleable.ChipDrawable_chipEndPadding, 0.0F));
    a.recycle();
}
```

This library does not have **app:closeIconVisible="visible"** attribute as can be seen from code. Seems like your version does not too. Consider using  app:closeIconEnabled="false" to hide and just setting the drawable(as you already are) to show. Although I would recommend to move to the latest version as permitted by you codebase because these libraries are very frequently updated in alpha versions.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Here is the link to official release notes to find out what's the latest version: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases